# Creating a Data Frame in Descending order for the sum of NaN values in each column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, format, row

I am trying to write a piece of code where it sorts the `NA_values` data frame in R in descending order. The `NA_values` creates a data frame from the sum of the `Nan` values in each column for the `data` data frame. The code for `Sorted_NA` gives the sorted order as a `num` structure below, however I just want the mutated version of the `NA_values` in descending order as a data frame structure in order to still see the columns with the associated number of `Nan` values. How would I be able to change the `Sorted_NA` variable below so that I can get the expected output below:

Code:

```
data <- data.frame(
   emp_id = c (1:6), 
   emp_name = c(515.2,NaN , NaN, 2 ,3,1),
   salary = c(623.3,NaN , NaN, NaN ,NaN,NaN),
   new_s = c(843.25,4,5,12,4,554.4)
)

NA_values= data.frame(NA_value=colSums(is.na(data)))
Sorted_NA = NA_values[order(NA_values$NA_value,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

```
                 NA_values
salary           5
emp_name         2
emp_id           0
new_s            0
```

Comment: Just `sort` your `colSums`. `NA_values  = data.frame(NA_value=sort(colSums(is.na(data)), decreasing = T))`

Comment: thank you, would you know how I could access the first X number of Column names in `Na_values`?

Answer (score 1):

One option

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.x)))) %>% 
  select(order(-unlist(.)))
```

-output

```
   salary emp_name emp_id new_s
1      5        2      0     0
```